# how to hide close button in iOS notification on apple watch

Tags: ios, notifications, watch

we're sending critical alerts to the user by remote notification. Users with an apple watch recieve those notifications at their watch display. at the bottom of the notification at the apple watch display, there is a "close" button displayed. If the user hits this close button, the notification seems to be purged by the os and the iphone app has no change to get the notification anymore.

As there is some data transported within the APNS Payload, this data is lost for the app.

We didn't do anything special for apple watch (like a watch app), we only deploy an ios app.

What is the preferred way to
a.) remove the close button in apple watch notification
b.) have the app to be able to access the notification payload if the user hits "close".

Any help appreciated

Comment: You can't do a) or b). The delivery of push notifications is not guaranteed. Your app should not rely on payload data in the push notification; it should be able to retrieve any required data from your server when it is opened.

Comment: But this means that if user taps a notification at his watch, the app doesn't even know about an incoming notification. That also means that we should prevent the watch from receiving notifications? Is this possible at least? The payload could be loaded from server, but if the app doesn't even know about a notification there is no trigger to load the data.

Comment: The purpose of a notification is to deliver information to the user, not the application. Apps should check the server for any updated information when they return to the foreground. The user can choose to not deliver notifications from particular apps to the watch but the app itself cannot.